# Python3 googleads.oauth2 module does not use proxy. Python2 does

Tags: python, oauth, double-click, squid

I have the following snippet of Python code to connect to Google Doubleclick for Publishers. It works fine in Python2 and Python3. However when using a (Squid) proxy, it does not work with Python3, since the call to accounts.google.com bypasses the proxy when using the Python3 googleads library.

*So my question is why is it that the call to accounts.google.com bypasses the proxy.*

And I don't make explicit calls to accounts.google.com, that is done by Google  googleads library. `pip install googleads`

I suspect that the googleads.oauth2 module is the culprit.  This is a code snippet:

```
from googleads import dfp
    from googleads import oauth2
    import httplib2

    oauth2_client = None
    try:

        proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, <proxy.host>,<proxy.port>)

        oauth2_client = (
            oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(<dfp.client_id>, <dfp.client_secret>,
                                            <dfp.refresh_token>, proxy_info=proxy_info
            )
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical("Could not init oauth client", e)

    httpsProxyUrl = "http://{}:{}".format(<proxy.host>,<proxy.port>


    self.dfp_client = dfp.DfpClient(oauth2_client, <dfp.application_name>,
                                    network_code=<dfp.network_code>,
                                    https_proxy=httpsProxyUrl, cache=None)
```

When running with Python2 the Squid log shows:

> 1454506480.333    788 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 399986 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::8b -
>   1454506480.737    236 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 4767 CONNECT 173.194.65.84:443 - HIER_DIRECT/173.194.65.84 -
>   1454506487.143   6399 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 900716 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::8b -
>   1454506492.123   1049 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 195254 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::8b -
>   1454506494.129   1928 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 7579 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::8b -

All ads.google.com connections, which is good. And one connection to 173.194.65.84 which is accounts.google.com, which is also good... I think, because I expect a DNS name and not an IP address. Strange.

When running with Python3 my Firewall notices an access to account.google.com. This is **not good**, since it bypasses the proxy. Traffic to ads.google.com still goes through the proxy:

the Squid log shows ads.google.com accessing. Which is good, but accounts.google.com is gone:

> 1454507105.115    924 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 401298 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::64 -
>   1454507114.449   6664 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 903366 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::64 -
>   1454507118.952    612 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 196015 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::64 -
>   1454507120.411   1391 ::1 TCP_MISS/200 7909 CONNECT ads.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4013:c00::64 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the googleads.oauth2 module is the culprit. It is the [HTTPLib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2/0.9.2) library. It seems that the HTTPLib2 does not pick up the proxy settings correctly as described in numerous places, for example here: [HTTP Proxy ignored in Python 3.4](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/issues/272)

I solved my immediate problem by proxying everything HTTP and creating a whitelist of IP addresses to bypass the proxy. I used this [socks](https://gitlab.tools.bol.com/rvanloon/google-shopping/blob/master/lib/googleshopping/socks.py) replacement.

Than the code becomes:

```
from googleads import dfp
from googleads import oauth2
import httplib2
import roaldsocks # socks rewrite

oauth2_client = None
try:
    roaldsocks.setdefaultproxy(roaldsocks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP <proxy.host>,<proxy.port>)
    roaldsocks.wrapmodule(httplib2)

    oauth2_client = (
        oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(<dfp.client_id>, <dfp.client_secret>,<dfp.refresh_token>
        )
    )
except Exception as e:
    logger.critical("Could not init oauth client", e)
```

Then everything goes through the proxy. If you want to exclude ranges you can add some code to the `create_connection` method in the aforementioned socks replacement. Something like:

```
            if ipaddress.IPv4Address(sa[0]).is_private or \
                        ipaddress.IPv4Address(sa[0]) in ipaddress.IPv4Network('<some range>'):
            sock = _orgsocket(af, socktype, proto) # set original socket
        else:
            sock = socksocket(af, socktype, proto)
```

Mind you this will only work with ipv4.